# Syncing project with the last commit from Github

Tags: visual-studio, github, git-commit, git-revert

Long story short:I made a few mistakes in the current developing session and I deleted some files which shouldn't be deleted(That's what I call fail refactoring).In the last commit on GitHub I can find those files.So my question is:is there any way that I could discard the changes I made today and go back in time to the last commit? If yes,which steps should I follow?

PS:I use the GitHub extension in Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

git reset --hard  actually did the job